# Wrapping text in <a> tags

Tags: php, html

I needed a script to wrap phrases with  tag, they all are separated by commas, for i.e "Alan, Bob, John".

I came to this result:

```
        $actors = explode(',', $item->casting);

        $item->casting = array_map(function($a) {
            $a = trim($a);
            return '<a href="'.$a.'">'.$a.'</a>';
        }, $actors);

        echo implode(' ', $item->casting);
```

I'd like to know is there a better way achieve this result ?

Comment: You can always use a regex. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't handle names with spaces within, nor names with characters that are illegal for URL's. To accomodate these two issues, you could use something like:

```
$item->casting = 'André, Ann Charlotte, Bob, Kåre Ronny';

$actors = array();

foreach (explode(',', $item->casting) as $actor) {
    $actor = trim($actor);
    $actors[] = '<a href="'. urlencode($actor) .'">'. $actor .'</a>';
}

echo implode(', \n', $actors);
```

Which would produce the following output:

```
<a href="Andr%C3%A9">André</a>, 
<a href="Ann+Charlotte">Ann Charlotte</a>, 
<a href="Bob">Bob</a>, 
<a href="K%C3%A5re+Ronny">Kåre Ronny</a>
```

I kind of prefer building the `$actors` array, as that allows me easily to change output variants. But you could also opt for using `echo` directly, which would eliminate the need for the entire `$actors` table. I did however removing the original `$actors` and included that directly in the foreach, as I try to keep intermediary variables to a minimum.

<sub>PS! Depending on font settings and encoding elsewhere, you could consider calling `htmlspecialchars()` in addition before using in the URL.</sub>

Comment: I guess he is going to print it as html. If so, we should avoid the comma between each <a> tags.

Answer (score 1):

Is this shorter version perhaps what you're looking for?

```
$actors = explode(', ', $item->casting);

foreach ($actors as $actor) {
    echo "<a href=\"$actor\">$actor</a> ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The @holroy solution is a good one.

I wanted to try using an alternative one, with the same preoccupations, but with less statements. Here is it:

```
  $source = 'André, Ann Charlotte, Bob, Kåre Ronny';
  echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/(\s*)([^,]+)/',
    function($matches) {
      return $matches[1] . '<a href="' . urlencode($matches[2]) . '">'
        . $matches[2] . '</a>';
    },
    $source
  );
```

But I also had the curiosity to control if it was more or less fast, and my solution takes 50% more time to execute. Sigh :). For 1000 times:

> use_foreach: 0.060003995895386
>   use_preg: 0.091005086898804

Comment: We should care about speed more than the lines of code!

Comment: @TareqMahmood. Not always though, but in cases where it is singificant like here, sure...